# Flutter one time choice radio buttons

Tags: flutter, radio-button

How can i make one time choice custom radio button like in the picture [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
  }
   class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
       int _selection = 0;

      selectTime(int timeSelected) {
       setState(() {
       _selection = timeSelected;
          });
         }

         @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Home"),
       ),

       body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selection = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 150,
                      color: _selection == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Radio(
                          focusColor: Colors.white,
                          groupValue: _selection,
                          onChanged: selectTime,
                          value: 1,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "11:00 - 12:00",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selection = 2;
                  });
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 150,
                      color: _selection == 2 ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Radio(
                          focusColor: Colors.white,
                          groupValue: _selection,
                          onChanged: selectTime,
                          value: 2,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "12:00 - 13:00",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
));
```

}
}

Comment: thanks, yeah its actually radio buttons, but i want something like in the picture button style. so when you press on button the color will change and radio button will be selected as well

Comment: In this case you can create a Stack widget, and put the Radio button on top of a container that has that color, then in that SelectTime()  u also have variable that stores which button was selected and conditionally change the color based on that selection. let me know if you need me to do the full solution

Comment: I have tried with the stack but when i click on container the value of radio  is not changing, i am newbie in flutter  please can you provide some example

Comment: @Amin I have edited to put the full code, you will be able to play around with it the way you want, let me know if that helps

Comment: You are welcome, if you are also new I recommend this  Udemy course https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/